# Creating grouped lists based on shared dictionary values in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, grouping

I have a dictionary of devices where each device has a list of other devices that it can collaborate with. Think of these as the devices that it is compatible to.

```
 devices = {0: [], 1: [9, 10, 14], 2: [9, 11, 14], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [9, 14, 15], 6: [], 7: [], 8: [], 9: [1, 2, 5, 11, 14, 15], 10: [1], 11: [2, 9, 14], 12: [], 13: [], 14: [1, 2, 5, 9, 11, 16], 15: [5, 9], 16: [14], 17: [], 18: [], 19: []}
```

I would like to be able to cluster these into a list of lists that contains all possible clusters that can collaborate together. A cluster can only contain devices that are all compatible with each other. In other words, if a cluster [1,9,2] exists then 1 must collaborate with both 9 and 2 and they must collaborate with each other as well. In this scenario the final result should look something like this:

```
[ [1, 9, 14], [2, 9, 14], [5,9,14], [5,15,9] [9,11,14,2], [10,1], [14,16]  ]
```

I may have made an error manually computing this, but I believe this to be all possible clusters of the items while satisfying their compatibility requirements.

However, I am having some difficulties translating this into code. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: Not clear what is required in the output

Comment: when 1 is collaborating with 9, and 9 collaborates with 2. Does that not mean that 1 collaborates with 2?. Also from the dictionary, 1 collaborates with 10, but in the final result, 10 is not in the list of 1

Comment: @AajKaal The items in the dictionary are all devices that either collaborate with other devices or do not. The devices they collaborate with are the ones in the value slot of the dictionary for each device (key), each cluster should only contain items that all collaborate with each other. The final output should be the list of all possible clusters of these devices.

Comment: @Onyambu Hello! No, a cluster can only contain devices that all collaborate with each other. In other words, if a cluster [1,9,2] exists then 1 must collaborate with both 9 and 2 and they must collaborate with each other as well.

Comment: A device can appear in more than one cluster however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a cleaner way to get the result, but this code works.

Note your result includes [2, 9, 14] which is a subset of [9,11,14,2]. The subset is removed in this code.

```
items = {0: [], 1: [9, 10, 14], 2: [9, 11, 14], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [9, 14, 15], 6: [], 7: [], 8: [], 
         9: [1, 2, 5, 11, 14, 15], 10: [1], 11: [2, 9, 14], 12: [], 13: [], 14: [1, 2, 5, 9, 11, 16], 
         15: [5, 9], 16: [14], 17: [], 18: [], 19: []}


grps = []

# create 1-1 groups
for g in items:
   for c in items[g]:
       if g in items[c]:
          grps.append([g,c])

# add other elements to each group
chg = True
while chg: # until no more elements added
    chg = False
    for g in items: # each single element
       for g2 in grps:  # check each existing group
          if g in g2: continue  # if not already in group
          ok = True
          for c in g2: # check each group member
             if not (g in items[c] and c in items[g]): # can we collaborate?
                 ok = False  # no
          if ok: 
             g2.append(g)  # add element to group
             chg = True
      
# check for subsets
for i,x in enumerate(grps):
   for j,y in enumerate(grps):
      if i==j: continue # same group
      if set(x) & set(y) == set(x): # if subset
         x.clear() # remove elements 

grps = [g for g in grps if len(g)]  # remove empty groups

print(grps)
```

Output

```
[[10, 1], [14, 5, 9], [14, 9, 1], [14, 11, 2, 9], [15, 9, 5], [16, 14]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this:

```
from itertools import  combinations

colaborate2 = lambda args, dic : all(x in dic[y] and y in dic[x] for x, y in combinations(args,2))

def group (x, dic, n=None):
  if n is None:
    n = len(x)
  for i in combinations(x, n):
    if colaborate2(i, dic):
       return tuple(sorted(i))
  if n > 1:
     return group(x, dic, n - 1)

def groupings(dic):
    m = set([group(val + [key], dic) for key, val in dic.items()])
    return [i for i in m if len(i)>1]

groupings(items)
[(5, 9, 15), (14, 16), (5, 9, 14), (1, 9, 14), (1, 10), (2, 9, 11, 14)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it took me few hours I am happy with the neat and clean solution. Understanding the requirement while coding took me 90% of the time. Lesson learnt - use pencil and paper first.

Code:

```
devices = {0: [], 1: [9, 10, 14], 2: [9, 11, 14], 3: [], 4: [], 5: [9, 14, 15], 6: [], 7: [], 8: [], 9: [1, 2, 5, 11, 14, 15], 10: [1], 11: [2, 9, 14], 12: [], 13: [], 14: [1, 2, 5, 9, 11, 16], 15: [5, 9], 16: [14], 17: [], 18: [], 19: []}
# manually calculated expected result [ [1, 9, 14], [2, 9, 14], [5,9,14], [5,15,9] [9,11,14,2], [10,1], [14,16]  ]
# true result [[1, 9, 14], [2, 9, 11, 14], [5, 9, 14], [10, 1], [15, 5, 9], [16, 14]]

def is_compatible(k,v):
    if v in devices[k]:
        return True
    return False
   
clusters = []
for k,v_list in devices.items():
    if v_list:
        cluster = []       
        cluster.append(k)
        cluster.append(v_list[0])
        for v_ele in v_list[1:]:
            v_ele_further_check = True
            for cluster_member in cluster[1:]: # check v_ele compatible with existing cluster members
                if not is_compatible(v_ele, cluster_member):
                    v_ele_further_check = False
                    break
            if v_ele_further_check:
                cluster.append(v_ele)
        clusters.append(cluster)

print(clusters)

unique_clusters = []
for cluster in clusters: # eliminate_duplicates
    if not sorted(cluster) in unique_clusters:
        unique_clusters.append(cluster)

print(unique_clusters)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 9, 14], [2, 9, 11, 14], [5, 9, 14], [9, 1, 14], [10, 1], [11, 2, 9, 14], [14, 1, 9], [15, 5, 9], [16, 14]]
[[1, 9, 14], [2, 9, 11, 14], [5, 9, 14], [10, 1], [15, 5, 9], [16, 14]]
```

Comments:

You can see I can easily get rid of function is_compatible but it adds to the readability.
The order of cluster in clusters is maintained correctly if that matters.